# pass a variable to an onClick method

Tags: java, android, static, android-activity

So I want to calculate the total amount of time that occurs from when the activity is created and when a button is pressed. I can do that with my current code, but it uses static variables which I know to be bad programming practice is there another way for me to do this.

my current code:

```
static long startTime=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quick_touch);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
        startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long time= endTime- startTime;


    }
```

Comment: just remove the 'static' keyword. While you're at it, make it private.

Comment: Where did you hear static variables are bad? They are only bad if you don't know how to use them correctly.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this as long as it works

Comment: static works, and it ain't as bad as you think, what may be bad is, judging from your codes, you may want startTime to be set in onResume instead of onCreate, image the situation where your phone screen is off then turn back on. And if you're so into cleaner codes, use setTag on the button, tag it with start time.

Comment: @ColeJohnson - static is risky in Android, unless you've taken steps with various Activity flags to insure that only one instance can be running in a given process - something that platform does not otherwise promise.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a static variable-  a non-static member variable would also work.  However, if you didn't want that cluttering up your activity at all you could make a private inner class for the onClickListener, and have it store that time in a member variable passed in via its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you present, a static variable would have no affect on the outcome of your code.

Also, there's no real reason to be using a variable when the value will be constant.

I recommend `final long startTime;` with no initial value.  Set the value (as you already do) during the `onCreate`.

```
final long startTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quick_touch);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public void onClick(View view) 
{
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long time= endTime- startTime;
}
```